# Ember.js - extending a Bootstrap plugin's function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to extend the hide method of the Bootstrap modal plugin. I have many modals throughout the application and I would like to have a blanket solution to close the modal when a user hits the browser back button (instead of having to add the function to each modal instance in the application)

I know in Ember JS, you can override a component by importing it, calling the super method and adding your own customization. How can I do this with a Bootstrap modal plugin? I am not familiar with how to import the node_modules file in this scenario.

Essentially, what I want to do is this as a solution for all modals in the application:

```
 $(window).on('popstate', function() {
   $('.modal').modal('hide');
 });
```

Comment: If the modal is not removed from DOM when the user transition between pages, cleanup logic seems to be missing in your modal component. May I ask why you aren't using [Ember Bootstrap](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/) but trying to use Bootstrap JavaScript directly? Integrating it well with the lifecycle of an Ember app (or any other single page application framework) is not a simple task.

Comment: The modal is not a component and there's no logic within the Bootstrap modal plugin to remove the modal when the user clicks the browser back button - that logic needs to be add to each modal but I am looking for a blanket way to handle it

Answer (score 1):

I think every modal that is open in bootstrap has the `modal-open` class. If so, you can do this with jQuery. You can put this code in an instance initializer, or any place that runs before your application.

```
import $ from 'jQuery';

//...

$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  $('.modal-open').each(function() {
    $(this).modal('hide');
  });
});
```

This doesn't have to do with Ember, just jQuery and Bootstrap. Make sure this code is not run if using Fastboot.